# Sphinx search based on datetime

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I have a field called 'createdOn' which of the type 'timestamp'. The values stored in it are as such e.g.: 2011-08-07 00:00:00

I would like to search by this attribute. For example in mysql I would do this :

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` where deleted = 1 and date(createdOn) = '2011-8-4'
```

I tried to set it up in sphinx as such :

```
sql_query               = \
        SELECT id, deleted, upvotes, DATE(createdOn) as createdOn, thread_title, first_post \
        FROM posts
sql_attr_bool       = deleted
sql_attr_timestamp  = createdOn
```

and in php:

```
  $cl->SetFilter ( "deleted",array(1));
  $cl->SetFilter ( "createdOn", '2011-8-4');
  $result = $cl->Query("");
```

But this gives me an assertion failed error.

Thanking you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute timestamp should have integer value.

In sphinx.conf:

```
sql_query = select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(createdOn) as createdOn from ...
sql_attr_timestamp = createdOn
```

and in php:

```
$cl->SetFilter ( "createdOn", strtotime('2011-8-4'));
$result = $cl->Query("");
```

Comment: Just for fellow newbie readers: do not forget to re-index your database once you make any sort of modifications, additions, deletions in the database.

Comment: Thanx and sorry I had to contact you through your blog. I think stackoverflow should make some sort of a communication mechanism also. Also whats the best way to contact you incase I have other questions here at stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of Sphinx you need to use [`SetFilterRange`](http://php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.setfilterrange.php), i.e.:

```
$createdOn = strtotime('2011-8-4');
$cl->SetFilterRange("createdOn", $createdOn, $createdOn + 86400);
```